# custom upload tool

Tags: file, upload

for my small printing business i would like to have an upload tool on my site. customer clicks on 'upload' after login in, it will show 3 drop down menu's to choose printing media and lamination film. With a width and height box to fill in dimensions and a box for contact number. after choosing the file and selecting the right options the file is renamed with above information.

is there any standard tool or easy to modify tool what can do this? or is it a lot of work to program this?

tkx
peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/ is a great place to start.

It will take a little bit of front-end dev and backend to set it up.

Another one that I have yet to use but hear good things http://valums.com/ajax-upload/